# I tried to run Java -version, and it said "The program 'java' can be found in the following packages"

Tags: software-installation, java

I just ran this:

```
java -version
```

But it gave this error:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

Comment: It. Is. Telling. You. To. Install. Java. Have you installed Java? Can you see it says to try `apt-get install <selected package>`? Did you try?

Comment: Why do people not even bother to read errors?

Comment: I don't believe that the question is irrelevant. I just tried to *completely* remove java from my linux. The message on console is ambiguous "(...) java  *can be* found (...)". It doesn't say that java was uninstalled and that those programs require it. I just upvoted the question.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you don't have Java installed on your system.

Run the following command in the terminal to install Java.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Or the latest version

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```